# Checks on SQL Server, is there any equivalent on PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, constraints

I'd migrated my SQL Server DB to PostgreSQL using the Migration Toolkit. However the 'checks' of some tables were not migrated. Is there any alternative to the 'check' functionality on PostgreSQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you check postgresql documentation first?

Comment: Well, I'd searched but didn't found anything that help, but maybe I need to search more, right? Sorry for that.

Comment: Yes, PostgreSQL has [CHECK constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS). What specific CHECKs weren't migrated?

Comment: thanks @muistooshort. I guess all 'checks' were not migrated. My SQL Server DB is huge so I can't check in all tables. But I have the list of the unsuccessful one's. 

Do you know a way to add this 'check' constraint by pgAdmin? Maybe adding the check validation (eg. CHECK (price > 0) ) on "default value' of the column.

Thanks again. Sorry if is a silly question, but I'm all day doing this migration and my brain is working well now.

Comment: I don't use pgAdmin, the documentation covers simple CHECKs like that doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, I get the eg. from the documentation that you send. I'll look further, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone with the same doubts in pgAdmin, the answer is very simple, I didn't realize the silly mistake.

It is only necessary to go on Properties of the table, go to the Constraints tab and change the dropdown before the 'Add' button to the 'Check' option ( like in picture bellow).

http://imgur.com/5MKmqyp